# Getting analysis of changes in MY brain upon cannabis consumption

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, cognitive-neuroscience, methodology, cognitive-modeling

I want to know if/how my brain differs from other brains. I'm also interested in knowing exactly how my brain changes when I smoke marijuana, as it is claimed that it affects individuals differently. Fortunately I live in the Netherlands. Is it likely that researchers would welcome me to come, scan my brain, let me get high and do some more scanning? If the case is that researchers crave material, then this seems like a win-win.

Comment: I don't really see a question here.  For a researcher that's studying aspects of "cannabis consumption", I'm sure they'd be happy to have you as long as you didn't fall under any of the exclusion criteria.  For this type of study recruitment, check in the newspaper of cities that have a well-known teaching hospital.

Comment: (but as to your main question, no, no one is likely to let you just get scanned for kicks, there are liability issues)

Comment: Check into organizations like http://www.qps-nl.com/earlystage_subject.html that actively recruit for those running studies.

Comment: I'm thinking it would depend greatly on the existence of ongoing research with a need for participants. MRIs are expensive and not always easy to schedule time with. The cost of finding participants is relatively trivial, so AFAIK they usually do it on their schedule, which means they may not be recruiting when you're available, or at all even. Furthermore, I doubt there's all that much for either of you to learn; individual differences in effects may be relatively subtle and hard to identify compared to the normative effects, which are well-understood already. I'd start there if I were you.

Answer (score 4):

Both the Amsterdam University (UvA) and Radboud University use a public online system for applying for participation in experiments. I forget which system UvA uses, but Radboud uses the sona system (just google it, you can creat an account). There you can see ongoing studies and apply for experiments. Both these cities are big research hubs for neuroimaging. And other universities surely also have similar systems for recruiting participants, but I don't have experience with them so I don't know.

That being said, nobody will tell you about the difference between your brain and other brains. This is simply not a topic of research. It's kind of like asking what's the difference between this grain of sand and all other grains - there are too many to list, the similarities stick out more clearly, and even if there are some differences who knows which ones are important. Neuroscience is a new thing, and we're still cataloging the basics. Unless there's something grossly distorted about your brain, nobody can give it a casual look and tell you something about your personality or behaviour. And if there is something grossly distorted, they'll contact your doctor, and not discuss it with you directly.

On the other hand, if there are marijuana studies you can take part and ask for feedback. At the Donders Institute in Nijmegen you can get a CD with your brain scan for your participation. But the feedback you get will depend on the question the researcher is asking. Typically this question would pertain to shared effects of marijuana on everyone, and not to individual differences. Individual differences studies are still rare, as they require huge numbers of participants while scanning resources are very limited and costly.